# How to implement the CSRF token mechanism for restful APIs?

Tags: xss, csrf, jwt, rest

Considering the following facts, using `CSRF token` for a restful API (which of course is intrisincly session-less) seems inevitable:

- storing `JWT` in `local storage`(any where other than `http-only cookie`) makes the API vulnerable to `XSS` attack.
- storing jwt in `http-only cookie` makes the API vulnerable to `CSRF` attack

So in order to make the API secure against, both `XSS` and `CSRF` attacks, `CSRF token` must be implemented in the system. My question is how?

1. Should I define a route like `/api/csrf` so that the client is forced to send a request (containing their `http-only cookie`, which holds their JWT) to that endpoint, before each POST/PATCH request, to get a `CSRF token` and attach the token to the aforementioned POST/PATCH requests?
2. Considering that there are no sessions, In server-side, Should I store the mapping to CSRF and user id(JWT) in database/redis?

Are the abovementioned solutions valid and secure? Are there any standard way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Do you need your API to be accessible from the browser?  If not, you can simply disallow cookie-based authentication and force the user to always specify a token in the `Authorization` header, at which point neither attack should be a problem.

Comment: Yes, it should be accessible from browser, and the frontend is an SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about your API - that is being accessed via web UI from a browser - being exploitable via XSS attacks, because it is inevitable.

If you have an XSS vulnerability, that can be used to [bypass any CSRF protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/can-csrf-protection-work-even-if-an-xss-vulnerability-exists), because the attacker can execute script on the trusted origin as the user.

In your example 1., XSS could be used to call `/api/csrf` with the users (httponly) cookie, the CSRF token can then be read out from the response, and the POST/PATCH request issued (the same way the actual app that used the API would do).

The important thing is that your API *does* have CSRF protection. How it is implemented doesn't really matter. CSRF tokens in a POST parameter or header would work fine and are the recommended approach; you could also send the API auth token in a custom header; and even a simple custom header such as `API: 1` [would work](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/csrf-protection-with-custom-headers-and-without-validating-token) as CSRF protection in most cases, as custom headers can't be sent cross origin (though I'd recommend one of the former approaches because it is more robust).